# Загрузить файлы Django с AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Нужен чтобы пользователь загружал видео на сайт с AJAX.
Вот мой файлы:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
style="display: none;" id="addvideoform">
{% csrf_token %}
<p class="erroraddvideo"></p> 
    <input placeholder="Имя" autocomplete="off" 
    id="addtitlevideo" name="title" type="text">
    <p class="poskimgvideo">Изображение</p>
    <input placeholder="img" id="addimagevideo" 
    name="image" type="file">
    <p class="poskimgvideo">Видео</p>
    <input id="addvideovideo" 
    name="video" type="file">
    <textarea placeholder="Описание" wrap="soft | hard" 
    autocomplete="off" id="addopisaniyevideo" 
    name="opisaniye"></textarea>
    <button id="addvideobutton" type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('kabinet/addvideo/', addvideo, name='addvideo'),
```

views.py:

```
def addvideo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get('title', None)
        opisaniye = request.POST.get('opisaniye', None)
        img = request.FILES['img']
        video = request.FILES['video']
        user = request.user.get_full_name
        VideoBlog.objects.create(
            user=request.usesr, 
            title=title,
            imgtitle=img,
            opisaniye=opisaniye,
            video=video,
            videotype='video'
            )
    return JsonResponse({'title': title, 'opisaniye': opisaniye, 'img':img, 'video':video, 'user':user})
```

JavaScript

```
    $('#addvideoform').on('submit', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
    $('.erroraddvideo').val('');
      var title = $('#addtitlevideo').val()
      var opisaniye = $('#opisaniye').val()
      var img = $('#addimagevideo');
      var video = $('#addvideovideo');

      $.ajax({
        url: '/accounts/kabinet/addvideo/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'title': title,
          'opisaniye': opisaniye,
          'img': img.value,
          'video': video.value
        },
        success : function(json){
           alert('Ok')
        },
        error : function(){
           alert('No')
        }
    });
});
```